# react native orientation issue not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

im developing app and orientation doesnt work
at first my react project is version 63.3
i add following command to android manifest.xmln

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   >
```

then i used react-native-orientation-locker in App.js

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker'
```

Orientation.lockToPortrait()

but nothing happend

### what try

i try changing app.json and add following command

```
"orientation":"portrait"
```

then i using useeEfect like this   `useEffect(() => { Orientation.lockToPortrait() }, [])`

then i try to change android manifest  `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"`

then add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to application tag in androidmanifest.xml

and try to add this in screens that i use navigationContainer and lock it with useEffect and without it but still the same problem

after all this update RN to version 64.2 but same problem appears

and in this case im locking to landscape to check the code is right application load with landscape and after loading application become portrait
something cause this issue and i dont know how can i find it
and when i use `orientation.lockToPortrait()` in the home or details screen it work with some issue but work
did i miss something??

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
  Orientation.lockToLandscape();
 }, 1000);
}, []);
```